# MySQL results in array with PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I generate a dynamic pdf in which one section relies on a system 'indicator' value for what it actually prints.

The system queries a member table which each member has a Type of 0,1, or 2 (thousands of rows).

At the end of the full query, I need the script to set a variable which is indicative of the whole of results returned by that type field.

For example:

- if in ANY of the type results returned there are values of 0, 1 AND 2, then set `$result = 100;`
- If in ANY of the type results returned, there are only values of 0 and 1, then set `$result = 200;`
- if in any of the type results returned, there are only values of 0, set `$result = 300;`
- "" there are only values of 1, `set $result = 400;`
- "" there are only values of 2, set `$result = 500;`

any good way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just do a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Type FROM Members WHERE ....
```

Which will return only 1 to 3 rows.

Then it's just a matter of a few `if`s.

PS: you are missing the case where you have 0 and 2.